# Next.js Manually Loads Pages via <Link> Without Ajax

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, next.js, i18next

I am using Next.js (with Redux, react-i18next, styled components and Express) and Next.js loads my pages without AJAX (with a hard load, no in-place content replacement). Unfortunately, I can't determine the issue of the problem. There's no error in the console (browser and server). Does anyone of you know how to debug this issue or has helpful tips about the problem?

Here's the code of my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const {parse} = require('url');
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-express-middleware');
const Backend = require('i18next-node-fs-backend');
const i18n = require('../hoc/i18n');

const port = parseInt(process.env.APP_PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({dev});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

// init i18next with server-side settings
// using i18next-express-middleware
i18n.use(Backend).use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector).init({
  preload: ['en', 'de'],
  ns: ['common', 'home', 'content'],
  backend: {
    loadPath: __dirname + '/../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    addPath: __dirname + '/../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}-missing.json',
    jsonIndent: 2
  }
}, () => {
  app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    // Translation routing
    server.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18n));
    server.use('/locales', express.static(__dirname + '/../locales'));
    server.post('/locales/add/:lng/:ns', i18nextMiddleware.missingKeyHandler(i18n));

    // Application Routing
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const {pathname, query} = parsedUrl;

      if (pathname.startsWith('/_next')) {
        return handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      } else if (pathname === '/') {
        return app.render(req, res, '/', query);
      } else {
        return app.render(req, res, '/content', query);
      }
    });

    server.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(`> Application server ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  })
});
```

The link itself is created with

```
<Link href={item.link}>
  <a>
    {item.title}
  </a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the server maps the dynamic URL correctly, the client-side still has to use the following link syntax to make it work (especially important is the "as" attribute):

```
<Link href={'/content'} as={'/the-real-url'}>
  <a>Test Link</a>
</Link>
```